# Phonegap Media.startRecord() Audio Format

Tags: cordova

What is Phonegap's Media.startRecord() recording format and sample rate? Is the format different per platform?

```
mediaRec = new Media("test.mp3", onSuccess, onError);

mediaRec.startRecord();
```

When I try to convert the file from MP3 to WAV with lame, it gives me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the encoding depends on the platform. So on android, the encoding is AMR.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: From Android SDK 10, AAC is available

Answer (score 8):

In android platform  Media.startRecord() record audio in MP3 format. In iOS it records in WAV format and that is the only choice. If you want record in  other additional format such as AMR in android use

```
navigator.device.capture.captureAudio( 
CaptureCB captureSuccess, CaptureErrorCB captureError,  [CaptureAudioOptions options]
```

);

Reference: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio

Comment: To make it clear, this answer is "technically" wrong. You can even record in a file like `record.asasa`. That means, it cares nothing about the extension and simply write the same data and play around with the extension.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding isn't as simple as just amr (at least from my experience). On my Droid Razr (4.1.2) and my work's Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (4.1.1) the formats were amr. On my co-workers Droid Razr M (4.2.x) the format was qcelp. On another work tablet, Asus ME301T (4.1.1), records in AAC

Reference: Fighting with phonegap for the last week (Sorry that is my best reference)